# LED on open circuit

Tags: led, switches

[image]

This circuit is not working where the transistor value is BC556B.

Any ideas?

Comment: "Not working" means what?

Comment: In what way is it not working? Not turning on when switch is open or not turning off when switch is closed? What LED are you using and what is it's maximum rated current? Does the circuit just not work or is one or the other component being damaged?

Comment: How much current will pass through your LED?

Comment: Sure looks like a circuit for a 12V lamp.

Comment: Also, BC556B is a PNP transistor, where your schematic calls for NPN. Can you give us the schematic of the circuit you actually built?

Comment: The circuit is not working, I need the LED to turn on when the switch is open. Maximum rated current is 20 mA. Transistor is cold.

Comment: I am a newbie and probably have no idea of what I am doing. I need a circuit that will turn on a LED when the switch is off and vice versa.

Comment: You're just missing a current limiting resistor in series with the LED. If you're using a regular red LED with forward voltage drop of 2V, then 1KOhm will let 10mA into the LED. But you'll have to replace the LED and/or transistor (probably just the LED) as per The Foton answer.

Comment: Thanks Ricardo. What should I replace the transistor with?

Comment: LEDs and transistors don't limit the current by themselves, so you need to place current limiting resistors in series with them. If you applied power to each of the circuits you presented, you burned the LEDs and may have burned the transistor. So I meant for you to place the current limiting resistors and AFTER THAT, replace the burnt components with new ones of the same kind.

Comment: Also, The Foton pointed out that you mentioned the transistor is BC556B (a PNP transistor), while your schematics says is a NPN kind (BC546, for example). The Foton showed a circuit where you can use the PNP transistor, so you have both circuits now. And, most importantly, The Foton circuit shows you how to use the **current limiting resistor in series** with the transistor.

Comment: Here are [some readings about the topic](https://www.google.com/search?q=current+limiting+resistor+circuit&safe=active&hl=en&source=lnms&sa=X&ei=q-9GU6jMKuaa0QHH84H4Ag&ved=0CAUQ_AUoAA&biw=1440&bih=815&dpr=1).

Comment: @Ricardo It's "The Photon" or "El Foton".

Comment: @ThePhoton! Right!! Sorry. I felt there was something wierd every time I typed it, but didn't know what it was. It can also be "O Fóton", in Portuguese.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume you're using an LED in the location where your schematic shows a lamp, because that's what your title says.

**first problem**

The schematic you showed wil most likely lead to blowing up either the LED or the BJT or both.

With the switch open, you have about 11 mA base current into the BJT. With a typical gain of 100, this means you are trying to pull 1 A through the led and through the BJT's collector.

If your LED is not rated for 1 A, it's most likely a goner.

1 A through the BJT collector, with about 9 V V<sub>ce</sub> means about 9 W of heat generated in the transistor. The maximum rating for the On Semi BC5556B is 1.5 W, so the BJT is probably smoked if the LED survived.

**second problem**

I just noticed that BC556B is a PNP transistor. Your schematic calls for an NPN type.

A PNP transitor needs a negative V<sub>be</sub> to switch on, and has a negative I<sub>c</sub> in forward-active operation. This means you need to change your circuit around a bit to use a PNP.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEMVy9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I "reversed" the circuit to use the PNP transistor you have on hand.

R2 limits the current through the LED to avoid excess current damaging the LED and/or BJT. You can increase R2 to increase the LED life at the cost of reducing the brightness. The value I showed (560 ohms) gives about 15-18 mA, depending on the type of LED. Currents as low as 1-2 mA will usually produce visible output, so there's lots of room to adjust this.

Comment: Maybe you should add to your answer how the OP could fix the problem, by adding a current limiting resistor in series with the LED. He isn't asking that, but it goes without saying.

Comment: @Ricardo, agreed.

Comment: What does it mean Vf of the LED>

Comment: @user2442708, it's the voltage when the LED is forward-biased. You'll find it as a line on the datasheet. Normally it's spec'ed for some particular forward current, but it's not very sensitive to the current.